# Find a parametrization of a half circle in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, spheres, parametrization

Let $B$ be a sphere with centre $(0,0,0)$ and radius $a$. Let $C_1$ be the path over the half circle of $B$ from $(a,0,0)$ to $(-a,0,0)$, and through point $(0, \frac{a}{\sqrt2},\frac{a}{\sqrt2})$. Let $C_2$ be the path that goes in a straight line from $(-a,0,0)$ to $(a,0,0)$.
Let $C=C_1 \cup C_2$.

How can I parametrize $C$? I'm having trouble because it's not in a $xy$ or $xz$ or $zy$ plane.

I found the parametrization of $C_2$, just having trouble with $C_1$.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to achieve this will be with a split parametrization: one for the diameter on the $\;x\,-$ axis, and another one for that thing on the upper hemisphere of the given sphere...

Comment: I know, I already have the $x-axis$ one, perhaps I should've mentioned that

Answer (score 1):

We will parametrize $C_1$ by  considering the "product" of two paths.
Let $\alpha_1$ denote the linear path from $(a,0,0)$ to $(0,\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $\alpha_2$ denote the linear path from $(0,\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})$ to  $(-a,0,0)$. Now set,
$$\gamma_1(t)= \frac{\alpha_1(t)}{||\alpha_1(t)||} \ \ \ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \gamma_2(t)= \frac{\alpha_2(t)}{||\alpha_2(t)||} \ \ \ \ \forall \ t\in [0,1] $$
Then set $\gamma=\gamma_1*\gamma_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If we find the plane containing all these three points, it has the equation
$$y=z$$

So the parametrization of $C_1$ will be as the following:
$$\begin{cases}x=a \cos t\\ y=a\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt 2}\\z=a\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt 2}\end{cases}$$
for $t\in [0, \pi]$